# vim - map keys to edit colorscheme and syntax files

Tags: vim, syntax, file-type, color-scheme

I have mapped `<Leader>ev` to open `.vimrc` for editing using:

```
nmap <Leader>ev :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

I now wish to map `<Leader>ec` to edit currently used `colorscheme` file, and also map `<Leader>es` to edit current `filetype` syntax file. I don't want to hard code the paths (or part of the paths) as I will be moving around between environments. It will help me quickly adjust color/syntax in middle of editing.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths from which Vim loads colorschemes, plugins, etc., are determined from the `'runtimepath'` setting. The `globpath()` function can perform lookups from it. By taking the first match, we'll get the path to the current colorscheme:

```
:echo get(split(globpath(&runtimepath, 'colors/' . g:colors_name . '.vim'), "\n"), 0, '')
```

Something similar can be done for filetype plugins; the current one is in `&filetype`.

To insert the path into the mapping, you can use `<C-R>=` (insert register contents, used with the expression register):

```
:nnoremap <Leader>ec :edit <C-R>=get(split(globpath(&runtimepath, 'colors/' . g:colors_name . '.vim'), "\n"), 0, '')<CR><CR>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Now I can easily adjust my vim without worrying. Up-voted, and accepted. Thanks!